# Are features for creating goals, viewing segments, and creating segments available on the Google Analytics Andoid app?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

There are many features that seem to be missing in the Google Analytics mobile (Android) app. Are these features hidden in some "expert mode" menu?

Example:

- I can't find how to create a Goal and many other settings etc.
- I can't find the segments that I created on the desktop usual website (analytics.google.com), only default segments are showed in the segments list
- I can't find an option to create a segment

Are all these options missing in the Analytics Android app?